# Block moving with constant velocity relative to another block beneath it, no friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

If you have two blocks with masses $m $ and $M$, all surfaces being frictionless, and you give a sharp impulse to say, the upper block with mass $m$, so that it has a velocity $v$, will the lower block also start moving?

I've seen many problems which ask for the velocity of the lower block, but I don't see how it could move in this case, as there is no force on it.

A related case is where the upper block is a person instead, who moves (against any friction) maintaining a constant velocity $v$ with respect to the lower block. I can see here that the lower block should start moving with a speed $mv/(m+M)$ (ground reference) from momentum conservation, the force that causes the lower block to move being supplied by the person. However, in the previous case, I don't think there's any such force.

I don't know what force is causing the lower block to move in the frictionless case, should it even move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if the question meant that even the surface between the 2 blocks is frictionless then there is no possibility of the lower block moving, even if the upper block is moving.

However if friction should be present; that is the only way the lower block could gain velocity(Considering no other force exists).

So if you had to find the velocity in such a case, you should remember that friction tends to oppose relative motion between the bodies.

So the finally both the upper and lower block would be moving with the same velocity. (Note I am only considering that friction exists between the blocks)

Hence with the above point and using your knowledge of physics (Momentum Conservation, etc depending on the situation) you can solve for the common velocity, which is the velocity of the lower block.